# Why am I getting "'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'AsBuffer'" with this WinRT code?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, arrays, bitmapimage, system.array

According to [this](http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/04/convert-byte-array-to-an-image-in-winrt), the following code can be used to convert a byte array into a BitmapImage:

```
public static async Task<BitmapImage> ByteArrayToBitmapImage(this byte[] byteArray)
{
    if (byteArray != null)
    {
        using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            stream.Seek(0);
            image.SetSource(stream);
            return image;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, I get, "*'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'AsBuffer' and no extension method 'AsBuffer' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*"

Is it that the "var stream" assignment is too vague (implicit typing) and I need to specify a particular data type for the "stream" var? Something other than System.Array?

Maybe this, from "[Windows Store Apps Succinctly](http://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/ebooks)" is a clue:
*Buffers/byte arrays—System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime. WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions: Extension methods in this class provide ways for moving between .NET byte arrays and the contents of WinRT buffers, exposed as IBuffer implementations.*

...but if it is, that's not enough info for me to know what to do with it. Instead of "TMI" it's "NEI" (Not Enough Information).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler isn't finding the [extension method](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/csharp-3.0/extension-methods/) [`AsBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598387%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Make sure you have a reference to the namespace `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime`, i.e.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
```

You also need to [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx) to the appropriate DLL, if you haven't already:

> Namespace:  System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime
>
> Assembly:  System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime (in System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll)

Comment: I tried to add the Reference, but got the err msg that it couldn't be added because it is already automatically referenced by the build system. So I added the using statement and it compiles. So that makes me wonder, if the needed reference is already there, why does VS not know that and give me a "Resolve" context menu item? Anyway, all's well that ends well, I guess - thanks!